# Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError:Map() (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.CaseInsensitiveMap)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I am trying load the data from excel sheet to hive table. It throws the error  below

```
.Map(treatemptyvaluesasnulls -> true, location -> "input", useheader -> true, inferschema -> true, addcolorcolumns -> false, sheetname ->"INPUT") (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.CaseInsensitiveMap)
```

Code used:

```
val df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") 
    .option("location", tname) .option("sheetName", fname) .option("useHeader", "true") 
    .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true") .option("inferSchema", "true") 
    .option("addColorColumns", "false") .load() //df.printSchema() //df.show(100) 
df.createOrReplaceTempView(s"""$fname""") 
//val d = hqlContext.sql(s"select * from $fname") 
spark.sql(s"""drop table if exists $tdb.$ttab PURGE""")
```

I tried with different dependecies.

Dependencies used:

- spark-excel_2.11:0.10.2
- com.crealytics
- spark-excel_2.10
  0.8.3

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved the issue :

used --packages com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.11:0.10.2

while running spark submit 
worked fine